Passing a character vector for code_folding in Distill
Reading distill  guilds and I'm trying to change the code_folding button in RStudio which says Show code' to different text, such as "Code Sample".
It says that you can pass a character vector to customize the text of the "Show code" button. Not sure what passing a character vector means and where you should pass the vector?
I've tried doing stuff like code_folding=TRUE<-"Hello" or code_folding<-"Hello" in the code chunk in RStudio. Doesn't let me knit the code.
EDIT: Solution is simple! Instead of putting code_folding=TRUE, put code_folding="whatever you want"!
